# Technical term for stray pixels

Tags: terminology

Is there a technical term to designate stray pixels (like clearly visible dots near contours) in raster graphics ? I seem to remember the word "kayatutu" from early Macintosh days but perhaps it was just a buzzword.

Edit: Here's an example with some clipart (zoom in to see the grey dots).

[image]

Comment: I use "schmutz."

Comment: Is there a reason why the term "stray pixel" is itself insufficient for your needs? If you could explain why, that might give more context so as to be able to answer your question accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the added example. In the picture of the dog, what is happening is that the stray pixels are the result of JPG compression (possibly combined with the white not being as pure as you thought before saving to JPG format). The compression algorithm is trying to reconcile the negative white space around the dog with all the colour within the dog, because JPG compression is looking for the best average colours across wide spaces. As in my answer, I would definitely call these "artefacts", but, again, please note that "artefacts" can also have other causes, such as bad aliasing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I refer to them as [artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aComputer_graphic_artifacts). The term is general for lots of different types of distortion, but the kind of stray pixels you are talking about could be the result of a number of causes, so for a more specific term you'd need a more specific situation.

Comment: Based on the newly added sample photo, this is the correct answer. It's typically referred to specifically (in the case of JPGs) as compression artifacting or JPG artifacting and is a result of how lossy JPG compression works.

Answer (score 2):

"Scum Dot" is the most common phrase I've heard in the printing industry.

I don't believe I've heard anything other than "Stray pixel" for on-screen work.

Answer (score 1):

"stray pixels (like clearly visible dots near contours) in raster graphics" is called `aliasing`

Comment: I'm not sure this would be a correct use of the term aliasing. Aliasing is not always undesirable, and does not always result in "stray" pixels.

Comment: I think Horatio's thinking of `jaggies`, and I think that's not what's being asked about.

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in language, and a picture is worth more than words in this instance. In the example you give it is certainly "artifacts" or "artifacting." It looks like jpeg quantization, and then someone used a magic wand tool to remove the white background, leaving slightly non-white areas. "Jaggies" is not a technical term.

Comment: @DaveMG: you are assuming that "stray pixel" has a defined distance, but a non-technical user might certainly describe non-smooth curves as having stray pixels. In any event the question has been clarified with a photo.

Comment: @horatio: Distance has nothing to do with it. The point is that "aliasing" is **not an error**. It's a **feature** that is sometimes useful and sometimes not depending on the desired outcome. The OP is asking about a *problem*, when pixels have undesired visibility. They may be the *result* of badly done aliasing, but aliasing is not, in itself, the problem or the description.

Comment: Aliasing is, by definition, a distortion or artifact. Do you mean anti-aliasing?

Comment: @horatio: No, I am talking about aliasing. While it is often visually unappealing, especially on video, it is **not** by default, a problem. Especially when you are designing for certain print needs, anti-aliasing is *not* desired, as it causes murkiness in the print process. Thus, whether or not you want to have "aliasing" depends on your goals. Since aliasing is not always a problem, but "stray" pixels are (because they're "stray") you can't simply equate the two terms.

Comment: aliasing has always been a problem, this is why one designs for high resolution and why line art was preferred to be 1200dpi.

Comment: I think you're confusing what aliasing is with what aliasing looks like when seen in unintended ways. In other words, of course aliasing looks bad if you are close enough to see the jagged edges. But then, so does anti-aliasing if you zoom in and see the gray dots. That anti-aliasing looks better at low resolution and on screens and aliasing looks better at higher resolution in print just goes to show that each has its place.

Comment: Again: aliasing is, by definition, an error and an artifact. It only "looks good" at high resolution because you have rendered it invisible. Anti-aliasing is a masking technique one uses when the resolution cannot be increased. In fact most digital processing techniques involve schemes to eliminate aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

An oldie question n_n

The artifacts shown in the image could be **JPG compression artifacts**.

1. JPG compression produces stains on flat zones, like the presumably pure white around the dog.

On Image **(A)** I have the clean original shape, and on Image **(B)** the same image is exported as a JPG.

Below each puppy, I posted the histogram of each image, and you can see how the **(B)** has no pure black or white values.

[image]

To exaggerate the pattern and view it I increased the contrast on both images.

[image]

I originally thought it could be **dithering**. Dithering is a dotted random pattern used when you have a limited palette, for example when the image is compressed as GIF or PNG8.

In Image **(E)** I have a 24-bit image with a "shadow" and on the right **(F)**, I have a dithered version.

[image]